# Конструктор копирования и explicit

Tags: c++

Имеется класс `Koords` и конструктор копирования для него:

```
Koords();
Koords(Koords &, unsigned = 0, unsigned = 0);
```

При этом если объявляю его как `explicit`, то перестает работать возврат `Koords` в функции, типа:

```
Koords fun()
{
     return Koords{};
}
```

компилятор пишет, что нет подходящего конструктора.. Но какого? Конструктор копирования есть и у него есть `Koords &` в первом аргументе, так что вроде никаких преобразований и быть не должно. Но мне компилятор говорит обратное...

Comment: Как насчёт [mcve]?

Comment: Если это собирается vc++, то это баг компилятора.

Comment: @alexolut вверху смотрите. Или пример для вас недостаточно минимальный? Или у вас какие-то проблемы, чтобы его воспроизвести?

Comment: Ага, проблема. В `fun` у вас используется конструктор по умолчанию, но его наличие в коде не указано. Т.е. пример не полный. Идеальный пример, когда код можно просто ctrl+c, ctrl+v и посмотреть на результат. Не додумывая ничего и не склеивая куски из разных частей.

Comment: да сдесь обычный `Koords()` - все.

Comment: В таком случае, обратите внимание на комментарий @VTT.

Comment: Непонятно, соблюдено ли правило трёх (или даже правило пяти).

Comment: @VTT, вообще говоря то, что последняя студия НЕ собирает этот пример является свидетельством неполноценной поддержки C++17 в ней. Последняя студия с ключами C++17/latest **должна** собирать этот пример. Другой вопрос, что она не собирает, поэтому непонятно, что там у автора за студия.

Comment: а у меня и не студия - у меня линукс

Comment: Тогда вам надо предоставить [Минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). И лучше сразу со ссылкой на онлайн компилятор с кодом.

Comment: уже не нужно...

Comment: Очень даже нужно. Потому что в описанном виде никаких проблем с кодом быть не должно.

Comment: Вообще-то есть. Покрайней мере при компиляции на линуксе. Иначе никакого вопроса бы не было

Comment: Если они есть, то надо предоставить [Минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). А без него [проблема не воспроизводятся](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hqxT5GkAjYkjPZlr).

Comment: Да елки ж палки: минимальный пример это код выше + Koords() в объявлении класса - я же уже писал!

Comment: Все-таки потрудитесь перейти по ссылке и прочитать, что такое [Минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) и все-таки предоставить его. И лучше сразу со ссылкой на онлайн компилятор, чтобы все могли сами убедиться в наличии проблемы. В текущем варианте (доработанном до состояния компилируемости) [проблема не воспроизводится](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hqxT5GkAjYkjPZlr).

Comment: Еще раз: уже не зачем!!!! Я по совету ответившего ниже добавил const и все заработало. Все - вопрос закрыт!

Comment: Вообще `const` в конструктор копирования добавлять конечно правильно, но оно должно было работать и без него. Я вам привел [конкретный пример](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hqxT5GkAjYkjPZlr) - видите, все и без `const` работает.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, на будущее: приводите версию языка (и компилятор!), которая Вас интересует. Для C++17 это рабочий пример, для более ранних — нет (безотносительно `explicit`). Поэтому от Вас и просят пример.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Очевидно у вас в классе есть поля и  не установлен инвариант по
  умолчанию. Потому у вас ошибка: нет соответствующей функции для
  вызова в `Koords :: Koords(){}`
- Ваш конструктор копирования компилятор  не воспринимает как
  конструктор копирования,  во избежании модификации копируемого обьекта
  (отсутствует спецификатор `const`). Компилятор может
  считать это просто как неопределенный конструктор и сообщить, что это
  неверная инициализация из `rvalue типа 'Koords'`.

  Это уже вторая ошибка.

Я напишу как надо:

```
class Koords{    
public:
    Koords() {}
    Koords(const Koords &, unsigned = 0, unsigned = 0);
};
```

теперь вы можете спокойно возвращать обьект с инициализатором по умолчанию.  `explicit  для коструктора коопирования?`.. Когда вы пишете конструктор копирования, вы и так явно копируете.. (Хотя это не относится к ответу на вопрос)

```
Koords fun()
{
     return Koords{};
}
```

Если не будете писать конструктор, то  как инициализировать ваш обьект, компилятор не знает. Придется возвращать просто неинициализированный обьект, заменяя фигурные скобки на круглые.
 Надеюсь вы понели, хотя никогда не буду утверждать, что умею хорошо обяснять

Comment: *"вас ошибка: нет соответствующей функции для вызова в Koords :: Koords(){}"* - не стоит выдумывать, если бы не было этого конструктора, то код бы не работал и до добавления explicit. Конструктор копирования тут вообще не вызывается. Кроме того, ОП так и не привел пример, демонстрирующий заявленную проблему, так что еще вопрос, была ли она на самом деле и какая.

Comment: @VTT, откуда такая уверенность, что придумываю я, а не вы.  Не соглашусь с вами, даже если вы себя считаете самым большим знатоком

Comment: как const связан с бесконечным копированием?

Comment: @Croessmah, да, я немного не то написал  (ошибка невнимательности), но раз копируемый обьект не константный, можно и такое написать в теле КК и не только такое. Но спасибр, что предупредили. Сейчас поправлю

Comment: Конструктор копирования не обязан принимать ссылку на константу. Первым параметром может быть просто ссылка, а остальные - заданы по-умолчанию.

Comment: Как уже ответил @Ant , проблема здесь в копирующей инициализации в сочетании с explicit.

Answer (score 3):

В вашем случае подходящего конструктора копирования у вас не уже хотя бы потому, что первый параметр вашего конструктора копирования объявлен как неконстантная lvalue ссылка. Такую ссылку невозможно привязать к временному объекту `Koords{}`. Поэтому до С++17 (см. ниже) работать это не может в принципе, и `explicit` тут ни при чем вообще.

---

Что же касается `explicit` на конструкторе копирования... Конструктор копирования по определению всегда являлся частным случаем конструктора конверсии. Объявление конструктора копирования как `explicit` производит на него тот же самый эффект, как и на любой другой "одноаргументный" конструктор. Такой `explicit` конструктор будет использоваться только в контекстах, соответствующих *прямой инициализации* (direct-initialization), и не будет использоваться в контекстах, соответствующих *копирующей инициализации* (copy-initialization)

```
struct S {
  S() {}
  explicit S(const S&) {}
};

int main()
{
  S s;
  S a(s);  // OK
  S b = s; // Ошибка
}
```

Возвращение значения из функции через `return` делается по правилам *копирующей инициализации*. Поэтому `explicit` конструктор копирования там использоваться не может

```
S foo() {
  S s;
  return s; // Ошибка
}
```

Обратите внимание, что в С++14 ошибочным по той же причине являются и такие варианты

```
return S(s);
return S();
return S{};
```

но начиная с С++17 именно эти варианты уже являются корректными из-за guaranteed copy elision.

Что интересно, даже в С++14 корректным является вариант

```
S foo() {
  return {};
}
```

но я навскидку не помню, какой "уголок" стандарта делает это возможным.

Comment: разве copy-elision отменяет семантические правила?

Comment: @Croessmah: *Guaranteed* copy-elision в С++17 отменяет. То есть в контекстах с guaranteed copy-elision больше нет требования наличия доступного конструктора копирования .

Comment: благодарю за пояснение.

Comment: От таких ответов, конечно, больше пользы...